# Request to WebApi DateTime Post using JSON object?

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api

```
   public object postDate(DateTime start)
    {
      //Save the DateTime to sql Server
      //return success code or object

    }
```

How's the json string look like to post DateTime?

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an object and wrap it to this like:

```
Public class SampleModel
{
    Public DateTime Start {get; set;}
}
```

then POST it to the Action:

```
 public object postDate(SampleModel sampleModel)
{
  // sampleModel.Start
  //Save the DateTime to sql Server
  //return success code or object

}
```

JSON must be like this:

```
 {
  "Start":"2017-05-11T09:18:54.092Z"
 }
```

Comment: how the json string look like when posting DateTime?

Comment: I put a sample of json in the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks it's okay now :)

{
 "StartTime":"2017-05-17 14:04:58"
 
}
Btw this one also working :)

Comment: Working for me without Z "Start":"2017-05-11T09:18:54.092"